# How to remove blank element in between non-blank elements in list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list that looks like the following:

```
myList = ['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz']
```

How would I be able to remove all instances of

```
''
```

in between each element that does not have a '' in it.  So, my new list would look like:

```
myNewList = ['', '', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz']
```

My initial thoughts were to just use a for loop to identify if a cell isn't a '' and then delete the next element like so:

```
myList = ['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz']

for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    if i != '' and myList[i]:
        del(myList[i + 1])
```

However, my list index is out of range. *Keep in mind that this pattern is the same throughout*.  Every time there is an element containing actual text, there is an extra blank line after it.

*Essentially I need to KEEP all elements containing '' unless they are directly after an element containing text.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the list is `['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz', '']`

Comment: Jesse could you be more clear on what logic you are trying to get the expected out.

Comment: Hey, I just need to remove a blank element in between non blank elements.  @thefourtheye, I would need to keep the first element of that list, but remove the '' in between foo and bar; keep the next two elements ('' and '') then remove the space in between 'fizz' and 'buzz'' and remove the last space.

Comment: @JessePet you want to remove balnks only when the number of consecutive blanks is less than 2 right?

Comment: @The6thSense Essentially I need to KEEP all elements containing '' unless they are directly after an element containing text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList = ['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz']

from itertools import groupby, chain

def consec(l):
    for k, v in groupby(l):
        lst = list(v)
        if len(lst) > 1 or lst[0]:
            yield lst

myList[:] = chain.from_iterable(consec(myList))
print(myList)
```

Output:

```
['', '', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz']
```

The only way you will get a single element list  returned with an empty string is if there is an empty string between two words. You have to catch the beginning and end as special cases but that logic can easily be added once you decide what should happen when there are single leading or ending empty strings. if you want to do it without chain you just need to iterate and yield each element:

```
def consec(l):
    for k, v in groupby(l):
        lst = list(v)
        if len(lst) > 1 or lst[0]:
            for ele in lst:
                yield ele

myList[:] = (consec(myList))
print(myList)
```

There are a few ways if you want to catch single leading or trailing empty strings and want to keep them, one way is to use enumerate and check the last list outside the loop:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain


def consec(l):
    for ind,  (k, v) in enumerate(groupby(l)):
        lst = list(v)
        if len(lst) > 1 or lst[0] or ind == 0:
            yield lst
    if len(lst) == 1 and not lst[0]:
        yield lst
```

Which should work for all cases:

```
In [2]: myList = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz', '',""]

In [3]: myList[:] = chain.from_iterable(consec(myList))

In [4]: myList
Out[4]: ['', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz', '', '']

In [5]: myList = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz', '']

In [6]: myList[:] = chain.from_iterable(consec(myList))

In [7]: myList
Out[7]: ['', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz', '']

In [8]: myList = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz']

In [9]: myList[:] = chain.from_iterable(consec(myList))

In [10]: myList
Out[10]: ['', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz']
In [11]: myList = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz', "",'foo',""]

In [12]: myList[:] = chain.from_iterable(consec(myList))

In [13]: myList
Out[13]: ['', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz', 'foo', '']
```

Comment: No worries,  I added a method to keep the trailing and leading empty strings  if you want to keep those too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use following simple code

```
myList = ['', '', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', '', 'buzz']
newList = [myList[0]]

for i in xrange(len(myList)-2):
    if myList[i+1] != '' or myList[i] == '' or myList[i+2] == '':
        newList.append(myList[i+1])

newList.append(myList[-1])
print newList
```

result:

```
['', '', 'foo', 'bar', '', '', 'fizz', 'buzz']
```